# Difficult bar chart animation -> updated state does not affect bar width as expected

Tags: reactjs, jsx, setinterval, use-effect, use-state

I have the following array with data:

```
export const DataSkills = [
  { id: 1, title: "Skillset 1", content: { Jira: [20, "../assets/Jira.png"], Confluence: [30, "../assets/Jira.png"] } },
  { id: 2, title: "Skillset 2", content: { Blubb: [80, "../assets/Jira.png"], Blabb: [50, "../assets/Jira.png"] } },
  { id: 3, title: "Skillset 3", content: { Beep: [60, "../assets/Jira.png"], Beem: [100, "../assets/Jira.png"] } }]
```

Now, I am using that data in order to plot a bar for each skill, for each skill set, like so:

```
{DataSkills.map((item, index) => {
  if (show[index] === true) {
    return (
      <div className="skill_divs" key={index}>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        {Object.entries(item.content).map(([name, [value, icon]], i) => {
          const barHeight = 60

          return (
            <div className="skill_container" key={i}>
              <div className="skill_name">{name}</div>
              <div className="bar_container">
                <div className="skill_icon_div" style={{ left: `${values[index][i]}%`, width: `${barHeight}`, height: `${barHeight}` }}>
                  <img className="skill_icon" src={icon} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="skill_value" style={{ height: `${barHeight}`, width: `${values[index][i]}%` }}></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <div className="skill_button_container">
          <div onClick={() => HandleShowButtonClick(index)} className="skill_button">
            collapse
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  if (show[index] === false) {
    return (
      <div className="skill_divs" key={index}>
        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        <div className="skill_button_container">
          <div onClick={() => HandleShowButtonClick(index)} className="skill_button">
            expand
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})}
```

Importantly, for the width of each skill-bar I am using a state:
width: `${values[index][i]}%`

This state, I create it like so on basis of the data:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(() =>
  DataSkills.map(entry => {
    let valueList = []
    Object.entries(entry.content).map(([name, [value, icon]]) => {
      valueList.push(value)
    })
    return valueList
  })
)
```

So, my state is an array which consists of arrays. Now, I am using UseEffect in order to have an animation of those bars upon loading of the page, from 0 to the determined value in my data, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (let id = 0; id < values[i].length; id++) {
      let value = values[i][id]
      let adjustedValue = 0
      let cloneValues = values.slice()
      cloneValues[i][id] = adjustedValue
      setValues(cloneValues)

      let interval = setInterval(function () {
        adjustedValue += 1

        cloneValues[i][id] = adjustedValue
        setValues(cloneValues)

        if (adjustedValue === value) {
          console.log(`adjusted value = ${adjustedValue} and initial value = ${value} `)
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
      }, 20)
    }
  }
}, [])
```

This almost works in that the bars are animated as I wanted them to be. However, the last bar for "Beem" should go all the way to 100, but it stops at 80 like "Blubb". I just don't know why, this is so frustrating -> as you can see, in the if-part for clearing the interval I am also logging the values to the console -> everything correct (with the exception that the order does not fit the order in the data):

```
bundled.js:11062 adjusted value = 20 and initial value = 20
 
bundled.js:11062 adjusted value = 30 and initial value = 30 

bundled.js:11062 adjusted value = 50 and initial value = 50 

bundled.js:11062 adjusted value = 60 and initial value = 60 

bundled.js:11062 adjusted value = 80 and initial value = 80 

bundled.js:11062 adjusted value = 100 and initial value = 100
```

-> so the bar should go all the way to 100, but it does not:

[image]

Even more confusing, if I press collapse and then expand again, reloading the state, then the bar is correct at 100, as it should be:

[image]

Comment: Can anybody help? - I now tried to solve my problem with "requestAnimationFrame" but the same thing happens :(